# C Bitwise operations left shift and bitwise OR

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Very short, I am having issues understanding the workings of this code, it is much more efficient then my 20 or so lines to get the same outcome. I understand how left shift is supposed to work and the bitwise Or but would appreciate a little guidance to understand how the two come together to make the line in the for loop work.
Code is meant to take in an array of bits(bits) of a given size(count) and return the integer value of the bits.

```
unsigned binary_array_to_numbers(const unsigned *bits, size_t count) {
    unsigned res = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
        res = res << 1 | bits[i]; 
    return res;
}
```

EDIT: As requested, My newbie solution that still passed all tests: Added is a sample of possible assignment to bits[]

```
unsigned binary_array_to_numbers(const unsigned *bits, size_t count)
{
        int i, j = 0;
        unsigned add = 0;
        for (i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--){
                if(bits[i] == 1){
                        if(j >= 1){
                                j = j * 2;
                                add = add + j;
                        }
                        else{
                                j++;
                                add = add + j;

                        }
                }
                else {
                        if( j>= 1){
                                j = j * 2;
                        }
                        else{
                                j++;
                        }
                }
        }

        return add;
}

void main(){
        const unsigned bits[] = {0,1,1,0};
        size_t count = sizeof(bits)/sizeof(bits[0]);
        binary_array_to_numbers(bits, count);
}
```

Comment: Could you show a sample call? And maybe your 20 lines?

Comment: Edited per request.

Comment: Two Down Votes? Maybe I don't understand how this site is supposed to work? I thought stack overflow was meant to be for **specific** code related questions. This post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work?rq=1 is an all time classic with 1230 upvotes and it is essentially "How does bit-shifting work?" A general question with answers that could be found many other places. I am posting about a specific use case, why the downvotes?

Comment: are you sure it's `unsigned res = 0;`

Comment: Yes, it was the number one ranked answer for one of the C katas on CodeWars. When you submit an answer there it is tested very thoroughly to pass all edge cases. Just realized I changed the return type during testing to int, just changed it back, I have double checked the code is identical to the original answer now.

Comment: Hopefully most of the downvotes came before the edits.

Comment: Could you explain conceptually what you expect the code to do by working through a concrete example?

Comment: I marked answer of Dagan as accepted, he stepped through the loop iterations explaining the operations and changes. This is expected functioning of code, I just needed help getting over the mental block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a breakdown:

- every left shift operation on a binary number effectively multiplies
  it by 2 `0111(7) << 1 = 1110(14)`
- consider rhubarbdog answer - the operation can be seen as two separate actions. first left-shift (multiply by two) and then OR with the current bit being reviewed
- the PC does not distinguish between the value displayed and the binary
  representation of the number

lets try and review a case in-which your input is:

```
bits = {0, 1, 0, 1};
count = 4;
unsigned binary_array_to_numbers(const unsigned *bits, size_t count) {
    unsigned res = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
        res = res << 1 // (a)
        res = res | bits[i]; /* (b) according to rhubarbdog answer */
    return res;
}
```

iteration 0:
 - bits[i] = 0;
 - (a) res = b0; (left shift of 0)
 - (b) res = b0; (bitwise OR with 0)

iteration 1:
 - bits[i] = 1;
 - (a) res = b0; (left shift of 0)
 - (b) res = b1; (bitwise OR with 1)

iteration 2:
 - bits[i] = 0;
 - (a) res = b10; (left shift of 1 - decimal value is 2)
 - (b) res = b10; (bitwise OR with 0)

iteration 3:
 - bits[i] = 1;
 - (a) res = b100; (left shift of 1 - decimal value is 4)
 - (b) res = b101; (bitwise OR with 1)

the final result for `res` is binary(101) and decimal(5) as one would expect
NOTE: the use of `unsigned` is a must since a signed value will be interpreted as a negative value if the MSB is `1`

hope that helps...

Comment: This is what I needed, this makes sense now when explained step by step. Sometimes something seems clear as day to one person who is familiar but to a newcomer it just doesn't click. Appreciate your taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

consider them as 2 operations i'll re-write `res= ...` as 2 lines

```
res = res << 1
res = res | 1
```

The firs pass `res` gets set to 1, next time it's shifted `*2` then because it's now even `+1`

Comment: So if `bits[i]` is 1 then it is OR'd by 1 so it remains 1 and `shift` is 1 then if `res` is 0 then how does res get a value? My confusion is with this, so you shift res(0) by shift(1). Is 0 shifted left by one not still 0? I am sorry I have a logic gap here, could you fill it in for me?

Comment: I know that leftshift is equivalent to left operand * 2^right operand. But 0 * 2^1 is 0. I am missing something.

Comment: @DocSpiegel i've edited my answer, you may want to look again

Comment: I will accept answer if you can quickly explain how, if res = 0 so 0000 0000 how does leftshifting it make it 1? Wouldn't that just cause one 0 to fall off and be replaced by another on the other end?

Comment: the left shift doesn't make it 1 it's the bitwise or of 1 `res = res | 1`